I'm trying to integrate Spark Connect(spark-connect) into my spark jobs. It throws circular import error for importing Spark Session inside Celery
I'm trying to integrate Spark Connect(spark-connect) into my spark jobs. For running the jobs in background I use celery combined with eventlet with concurrency of 5. This works fine for Spark Cluster which is setup in local, which has a Master and one Worker node.
spark = SparkSession.builder \
                 .master(settings.SPARK_MASTER) \
                 .appName(self.__app_name)

This works fine inside celery.
I tried to integrate spark connect into the existing jobs
spark = SparkSession.builder.remote("sc://xx.x.xxx.71:15002").getOrCreate()

This fails when run inside celery with eventlet pool, but works with solo pool. I enabled debug log for pyspark and found that there is a partial import error which is failing my jobs
ERROR/MainProcess] Task conn.union[afd002b6-39ca-4c51-b017-2ffd06f51c35] raised unexpected: ImportError("cannot import name 'SparkSession' from partially initialized module 'pyspark.sql.connect.session' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\\SCAD\\ifp-dataprep\\tenv\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyspark\\sql\\connect\\session.py)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SCAD\ifp-dataprep\tenv\Lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 477, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\SCAD\ifp-dataprep\tenv\Lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 760, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\SCAD\ifp-dataprep\django\conn.py", line 26, in union
    spark = SparkSession.builder.remote("sc://xx.x.xxx.71:15002").create()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\SCAD\ifp-dataprep\tenv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 524, in create
    from pyspark.sql.connect.session import SparkSession as RemoteSparkSession
ImportError: cannot import name 'SparkSession' from partially initialized module 'pyspark.sql.connect.session' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\SCAD\ifp-dataprep\tenv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\connect\session.py)

What is causing this issue? Is it due to concurrency? How can I fix this?
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_LOG_LEVEL'] = 'DEBUG'
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

from celery import Celery

app = Celery('myapp', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


@app.task
def union():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.remote("sc://xx.x.xxx.71:15002").create()
    adf = spark.read.parquet("s3a://dataprep/datasets/0b1018bd-5558-4932-b98a-46996a97663d.parquet",inferSchema=True)
    bdf = spark.read.parquet("s3a://dataprep/datasets/f6bdd428-fb5e-4942-b236-1c8efcc1d2d3.parquet",inferSchema=True)
    adf.show()
    bdf.count()
    common_columns = list(set(adf.columns) & set(bdf.columns))

    # Add missing columns to df1 filled with null values
    for col in set(bdf.columns) - set(adf.columns):
        adf = adf.withColumn(col, lit(None))

    # Add missing columns to df2 filled with null values
    for col in set(adf.columns) - set(bdf.columns):
        bdf = bdf.withColumn(col, lit(None))

    # Select only the common columns from each DataFrame
    df1_common = adf.select(common_columns)
    df2_common = bdf.select(common_columns)

    # Union the DataFrames
    # result = df1_common.union(df2_common)
    dfs = [df1_common,df2_common]
    result = reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.union(df2), dfs)
    result.show()

